# Onto the notation and interpretation of queueing theory-related markov chains

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory

If in a server with probability $p$ one job arrives and independently with probability $q$ one job departs, could you please explain to me what is the quantity and let me know if I have understood? The queue is infinite.

Note that during a time step, we might have
both an arrival and transmission, or neither.

$1$. $r=p(1-q)$: This denotes the probability that there is a job at the server right? i.e in Markov chain notation $\mathbb P(X_n=1| X_{n-1}=0)$

$2.$  $s=q(1-p)$: This denotes the probability that there is no job at the server right? i.e in Markov chain notation $\mathbb P(X_n=0| X_{n-1}=1)$ (I am not sure)

$3.$ What is the quantity $r+s$ denotes?

$4.$ What about $1-(r+s)$?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can only one job arrive and one job depart per time step? If so, then 1 and 2 are correct, and you can understand $r+s=P(X_n \neq X_{n-1})$ and $1-(r+s)=P(X_n=X_{n-1})$.

Comment: Note that during a time step, we might have
both an arrival and a transmission, or neither. What does this mean, Ian? Thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: It means what you've taken into account: to stay at the same queue length you can *either* have nothing happen *or* have both an arrival and a departure. To increase in queue length you need to have *both* an arrival *and* no departure. To decrease in queue length you have to have *both* a departure *and* no arrival. (This is assuming that you can never have more than one of either category of event in the same time step.)

Comment: The queue length is infinite it is given.

Comment: OK, in that case you can generalize by saying that $r=P(X_n=X_{n-1}+1)$ and $s=P(X_n=X_{n-1}-1)$ (no need to restrict attention to the case where $X_{n-1}=0$ or $1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $r$ is the probability to have an arrival and no departure, i.e. $P(X_n=X_{n-1}+1)$.
2. $s$ is the probability to have a departure and no arrival, i.e. $P(X_n=X_{n-1}-1)$.
3. $r+s$ is the probability that the queue length changes, i.e. $P(X_n \neq X_{n-1})$.
4. $1-(r+s)$ is the probability that the queue length doesn't change, i.e. $P(X_n=X_{n-1})$.